# Best practice for troubleshooting consistently poor website load performance? (Joomla! 3.1)

Tags: performance, joomla3.0

Following complaints of poor load times- I recently ran a performance benchmark on a new, Joomla 3.1-based website.

Below are the results of the benchmark analysis:

[image]

Detailed rating here:

http://www.webpagetest.org/result/131105_EK_1TM/

It appears there is not a single, isolated issue causing performance problems. Minimum scores were obtained in almost *every* category- so I suspect there are multiple issues that need resolving.

Can anyone suggest a starting point for troubleshooting a situation like this? What would be a comprehensive, best-practice method for troubleshooting a site with consistently poor performance across the board?

Any specific server hardware specification (or database configuration) questions I should be asking the hosting provider would be appreciated as well.

Here is the site URL for anyone who is interested: d g h solu tions . c a

Looking forward to hearing your thoughts or suggestions on this.

Comment: Who is your hosting provider? Are you on Shared hosting?

Comment: It's on shared hosting. "Ens ure H ost ing" (without the spaces). Recommended by my web designer as they have Linux servers which supposedly work quite well with Joomla. (Well, better than Go Daddy anyway.)

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would run the test here: http://tools.pingdom.com/ but if you insist running it on the one you are running it on, click the red boxes. Perhaps you missed this as they give you a detailed report of what is happening. Also consider a CDN with cloudflare is my call.

Edit: I would also make sure you are running it on a premium server, Stormondemand cloud servers work real well for us combined with the CDN - we're loving it!

Comment: I like that- it returns results much faster. I think I will use multiple speed tests to make sure I don't miss anything.

Answer (score 1):

Start off with two things:

**Monitor your Site with WebCron**
You need to work out if it is during certain times of the day and if you are having down time It is very cheap and gives you good graphs. If you find you are having big slow ups and speed ups it is likely your host has two many sites on a single server.
http://webcron.org/

**Google Speed Test**
Google's Speed test is another place to go to see what is taking ages to load. https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/

If you tell us about your website your even give a link we might be able to help a bit more.

Comment: d gh s olu t ions .c a (without the spaces). It's still a work in progress with a few rough edges being worked out and content coming in. Hopefully I can nip these performance issues in the bud.